# Showing that the limit of random variables is neither continuous nor discrete (base 3 representations)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, ternary-expansion

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be i.i.d such that $X_i\in\{0,1\}$ with probability $1/2$ each. Let $R_n=\sum_1^n2X_i3^{-i}$.

It is easy to show that $R_n$ converges almost surely, and that the limit takes the values in $[0,1]$ that can be written in ternary (base-$3$) using only $0s$ & $1s$.

I have shown that the limit cannot be a discrete random variable, since the set of possible values is uncountable, and I am also quite sure it is not continuous either, but I cannot think of a straightforward way to show this! How can I show this?

I have only studied basic analysis and fundamentals of Riemann integration so it would be great if any help could not go too complex! Thank you

Comment: This is the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).  It is continuous in the sense that it has a continuous CDF (you can show no point has positive probability), but not [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) and does not have a positive density anywhere.  So it is called a [singular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution):  a probability distribution concentrated on a set of Lebesgue measure zero, where the probability of each point in that set is zero

Comment: Ok thank you. How could I simply show it is not absolutely continuous?

Comment: That is a consequence of  the probability distribution being concentrated on a set of Lebesgue measure zero, and also that the derivative of the CDF is $0$ almost everywhere

Comment: Is this similar to the points in $[0,1]$ that the variable cannot reach being dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: It is slightly related to that, though there are other [nowhere-dense sets which have positive Lebesgue  measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set#Nowhere_dense_sets_with_positive_measure)